# Prove that $FG$ is tangent to a fixed circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, problem-solving, quadrilateral

> Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle with $2AB=BC$.
>
> $E$ is a mobile point on $AD$.
>
> $AB\cap CE=\{G\}$ and $CD\cap BE=\{F\}$.
>
> Prove that $FG$ is tangent to a fixed circle.

[image: Diagram]

Can someone help me? I don't know how to start this type of problem.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question?

Comment: yes but i deleted because i realised that the picture wasn't good

Comment: Why are you stuck? People are more likely to answer your question if they can see you have put in some effort yourself first. In this case, you could explain techniques you thought might have been useful, but were not as this gives people a basis for your level of knowledge, meaning they can write an answer you can understand

Comment: Also, all posts have an edit button (just above these comments), so in future you can just edit when you realise a picture is bad, rather than deleting and recreating the same question

Comment: Well, if $E$ coincides with $A$ or $D$ then $FG$ is vertical. So your circle must have diameter $AD$, with centre half-way between lines $AB$ and $CD$. And if $E$ is the mid-point of $AD$, then the circle has centre on $AD$. So now you know what the fixed circle must be.

Comment: yes,, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Say that $DF=ax$, then due to similarity, $AG=\frac{x}{a}$. Then we calculate $FG=\sqrt{(2x)^{2}+(ax-\frac{x}{a})^{2}}=ax+\frac{x}{a}$

We now know that $BG+FC=BC+FG$ and therefore $BCFG$ is a quadrilateral circumscribing a circle. Furthermore, $BG//CF$ with distance $2x$, thus the circle is always the same circle with $AD$ as diameter regardless of position of $E$

Comment: Thank you.......